# Display Parent-Child relationship in a table view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, hierarchy

I have a model Course, Components and Subcomponents:

```
public class Course
    { 
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Component> Components { get; set; }
}

 public class Component
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponents { get; set; }

}

public class Subcomponent
    {
        public virtual int SubcomponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string TypeSub { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameSub { get; set; }

        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subcomponent Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Childs { get; set; }

        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

}
```

The subcomponents have a parent-child relationship so **each subcomponent can have multiple subsubcomponents and so on**. I have a table in a view to show all the components and their subcomponents with different levels, but when i get to the subsubcomponents, if i create a subcomponent for that subsubcomponent it gets in the same level. How can i do to make a space or something to differenciate the hierarchy when its a subcomponent of another subsubcomponent and so on? I already searched and tried many ways but nothing works for me. Should i create a partial view for the subcomponents and then call it in the view with the main table?
In the view i have this:

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
           ...  
        @foreach (var item in Model.Components)
        {
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            ...
 @if (item.Subcomponents.Count != 0)
       {
         <table>
           ...
                 @foreach (var x in item.Subcomponents)
                        {
                           if (x.ParentId == 0) {
                               <td>
                                  >>
                               </td> 
                               ...


     @foreach (var y in x.Childs) {
                                    <td>
(subsubcomponents and subsubsubcomponents and so on stay in this level always)
                                       >>>>
                                     </td>
                                  ...
```

**EDIT:**
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Planificacao(int id = 0)
        {
            Course course = db.Courses.Find(id);
            if (course == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(course);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use partial views for this and I would probably recommend it. The idea is to create a recursive loop to iterate through the `Component.Subcomponent` collection and output some html for each Subcomponent and it's Subcomponents (Childs)

I wrote a @helper that you can add to a View, to show you how it can be done.

```
@helper BuildSubTree(List<HelloWorldMvcApp.Subcomponent> subcomps) {
    if (subcomps != null && subcomps.Any()) {
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subcomponent Id</td>
                    <td>Type Sub</td>
                    <td>Name Sub</td>
                <tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var sub in subcomps)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@sub.SubcomponentId</td>
                    <td>@sub.TypeSub</td>
                    <td>@sub.NameSub</td>
                </tr>
                if (sub.Childs != null && sub.Childs.Any())
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">@BuildSubTree(sub.Childs)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }           
}
```

Then in your view you can call this helper like this.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Course ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.CourseId</td>
            <td>@Model.Name</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var comp in Model.Components) {
            <tr>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Component Id</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@comp.ComponentId</td>
                            <td>@comp.Type</td>
                            <td>@comp.Name</td>
                        </tr>
                        @if (comp.Subcomponents.Any())
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    @BuildSubTree(comp.Subcomponents)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i created a [**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BBsGC) to show you how it can all work together.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. It's almost working, but the subsubcomponents keep repeating in the subcomponent level. I had this problem when i made the table in the question but i resolved it by adding `if (x.ParentId == 0) {` before the first time to use subcomponents, i tried to put there that if but didn't work. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Might be the way you're populating your model.. maybe you can post that code

Comment: I'm just adding in the database directly or using a method to add them, in either way that problem happens. If it helps, i added the controller for that view